# Intercept Requests in Network - Xamarin WebView

Tags: c#, xaml, webview, xamarin.forms

I am building a simple application using Xamarin. (c# and xaml)

I created a webView and opened a random YouTube video in it. The thing is I want to read all the requests/calls that are called by YouTube's link.

[image: Link's Network]

I want to intercept these requests/calls and do something with them.

Is there a way to intercept them and control them in the c# code?

Answer (score 0):

`WebView` has the method that you need:

> [shouldInterceptRequest(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient#shouldInterceptRequest%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29)
>
> Notify the host application of a resource request and allow the application to return the data.

Comment: And for iOS you can use canInitWithRequest: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/foundation.nsurlprotocol.caninitwithrequest?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12  
HOWEVER: you can't do that with WkWebView. Only with the old UIWebView, unfortunately.